# Angular: Ligar vários campos a um reactive form

Tags: angular, html-select

O problema é que possuo vários select multiple e quando seleciono algumas opções de um select elas são adicionadas ao ReactiveForm corretamente, porém quando eu seleciono alguma opção de outro select elas são sobre escrevidas, preciso que não se sobreescrevam. Eles são gerados automaticamente.

```
this.form = this.builder.group({
  id: [],
  permissoes: ([{}]),
}, {});

<div class="col-md-6">                                 
    <select class="form-control" formControlName="permissoes" [compareWith]="compareFn" multiple>
        <option *ngFor="let permissao of permissoes" [ngValue]="permissao">{{permissao.nome}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Todos os selects são iguais, é possivel eu juntar todos os selects neste array de permissões ?

Comment: Olá @Eduardo, bem vindo ao **SOpt**. Aproveite para fazer o [Tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para conhecer melhor o funcionamento do site.

Comment: Questão relacionada [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/328082/4272)

Answer (score 0):

Pra cada select ou input que vc tiver vc tem que adicionar uma linha correspondente quando criar seu form. E atraves do campo formControlName vc mappeia cada select/input pro seu respectivo controle.

```
this.form = this.builder.group({
  id: [],
  permissoes: ([{}]),
  outroSelect: ([{}]),
});

<div class="col-md-6">                                 
    <select class="form-control" formControlName="permissoes" [compareWith]="compareFn" multiple>
        <option *ngFor="let permissao of permissoes" [ngValue]="permissao">{{permissao.nome}}</option>
    </select>
</div>

 <div class="col-md-6">                                 
        <select class="form-control" formControlName="outroSelect" [compareWith]="compareFn" multiple>
            <option *ngFor="let outraCoisa of outroSelect" [ngValue]="outraCoisa ">{{outraCoisa .nome}}</option>
        </select>
  </div>
```

Comment: Esqueci de mencionar que eles são gerados automaticamente do banco de dados.

Comment: Como assim? Vc pode usar o formArray nesse caso talvez então.